# Alamofire Failure: invalidURL when i using json on url

Tags: swift, alamofire

My Fetch Code as below:Url type is string but when i send json format to url ,get error.
Please hel.i did share my function and error screen as below.

```
public func fetch<T:Codable> (headers:HTTPHeaders,_ method: HTTPMethod, url: String, requestModel: T?, model: T.Type, completion: @escaping (AFResult<Codable>) -> Void)
{
    AF.request(
        url,
        method: method,
        parameters: NetworkManager.toParameters(model: requestModel),
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: headers
    )
    .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
            case .success(let value as [String: AnyObject]):
                do{
                    let responseJsonData = JSON(value)
                    let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(model.self, from: responseJsonData.rawData())
                    completion(.success(responseModel))
                }
                catch let parsingError{
                    print("Success (error): \(parsingError)")
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failure: \(error)")
                    completion(.failure(error))

                default: fatalError("Fatal error.")
                
            }
    }
}
```

My Using Method:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import  Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class SorularController {
    
    var arraySorular:[Soru] = []
    public func GetSorularByDersId(dersId:Int,headers:HTTPHeaders,completion: @escaping ([Soru])->()){
        NetworkManager.instance.fetch(headers: headers, HTTPMethod.get, url: #"https://app.kivacrm.com/api/v1/data/osym/sorular?filters={"ders":["=",3]}"#, requestModel: nil, model: Soru.self) { (response) in
            switch(response)
            {
                case .success(let model):
                    let soruModel=model as! Soru
                self.arraySorular.append(soruModel)
            case .failure(_) :break
                
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to learn about URL encoding, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order your URL to be valid, get parameters must be url encoded.

Try to pass your `filters` parameter to `parameters` dictionary and use `URLEncoding` instead of `JSONEncoding` for this call:

```
AF.request(
    "https://app.kivacrm.com/api/v1/data/osym/sorular",
    method: .get,
    parameters: ["filters": #"{"ders":["=",3]}"#],
    encoding: URLEncoding.default,
    headers: headers
)
```